# Forgot to do config ignore before building webform. How to correct it and ignore the webform from the export?

Tags: webforms

Complete newbie to Drupal here. I forgot to configure my config ignore before I built a webform. 
I have now managed to do add webform.webform* to the config ignore but that doesn't solve my problem since the webform has already been exported. 
How do I fix the import/export settings in order to remove the webform?

Comment: If you are using git, you can just undo the changes to the configuration files.

Comment: Hi, are you using the [config_ignore](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_ignore) module? I've never used this module before, but it sounds like it only works when you're *importing* config, preventing your existing loaded configuration from being overridden/reverted to the exported config in the filesystem. What are you trying to achieve? If you want to not export specific config, then [config_split](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_split) may work for you

Comment: I also recommend using config_ignore with config_split. @see https://www.jrockowitz.com/blog/managing-webform-configuration

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your reply and apologies for my late response. Yes, I am using config_ignore and config_split module. I just added webform to config_ignore and then deleted the files from the git repository so next time they will not be added to git. Worked.